# What does synchronized mean in context of Vector / ArrayList?

Tags: java, vector, arraylist, synchronization

I've just read up some [information](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2001-06/03-qa-0622-vector.html) on `Vector` and `ArrayList`. From what I can understand `Vector` is obsolete compared to `ArrayList`. But `Vector` is synchronized whilst `ArrayList` is not.

But what does that mean? What does it mean when we say that a `Vector` is synchronized? And when is this useful?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It means that multiple threads can modify the Vector in parallel without risk of data corruption.

If you want to do this with an ArrayList, you need to use the `synchronized` keyword.

Comment: +1, or use the lock mechanism from `java.util.concurrent` package.

Comment: ... or the wrapper class created by `Collections.synchronizedList`, or (more generally) a concurrent list implementation class.